# Google app script load unknown dimensioned array into a spreadsheet gets contradictory messages

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
  let mysteryArr = [["question1","","","","","","","",""]
    ,["apple","banana","cantalope","date","grapes","apricot","tangerine","orange","pineapple","prune"]
    ,[24,16,8,20,8,8,4,16,12,4]]

  let maRows, maCols;
  if (mysteryArr.length != '')   {
    maRows = mysteryArr.length;
    console.log('num rows: ' + maRows);
  }  else  {
    console.log('No array');
    return;
  }

  for (i = 0 ; i < maRows ; i++ ) {
    if (mysteryArr[i].length != '')   {
      maCols = mysteryArr[0].length;
      console.log('num cols in row ' + i + ' is ' + maCols);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(mysteryArr[0] ) );
    }  else  {
      console.log('Array was 1D');
      return;
    }
  }
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if ( sheet == '' )    {
    ss.insertSheet('Sheet1');
  }  else  {
    sheet.clear();
  }
```

Message details
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 9 but the range has 10. (line 47, file "array2Sheet1")

How can these both be true? What is the correct way to determine the dimensions of an unknown array and load it into a spreadsheet?

Comment: setValues() requires a rectangular array

Comment: Your debug is wrong. It should be `maCols = mysteryArr[i].length;` not `[0]`

Comment: Thank you - I was being so careful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

The first row in your data has `9` elements but it should have `10` as the other two rows. Adding a new element will fix the issue:

```
   let mysteryArr = [["question1","","","","","","","","",""] // a new "" is added here
    ,["apple","banana","cantalope","date","grapes","apricot","tangerine","orange","pineapple","prune"]
    ,[24,16,8,20,8,8,4,16,12,4]]
      
  const shtRng = sheet.getRange(1, 1, mysteryArr.length, mysteryArr[0].length);
  shtRng.setValues(mysteryArr);
```

**Issue:**

You can also see the issue in the lengths.

- `mysteryArr[0].length` has a length of `9`.

But the **greatest** size in your array is `10` because the other rows contain `10` elements:

- `mysteryArr[1].length` has a length of `10`,
- `mysteryArr[2].length` has a length of `10`.

`setValues` will assume the greated size to be the correct one and hence the discrepancy. Every row in the data must have the same length.

Comment: Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug num rows: 3
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug num cols in row 0 is 9
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug ["question1","","","","","","","",""]
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug num cols in row 1 is 9
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug ["question1","","","","","","","",""]
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug num cols in row 2 is 9
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug ["question1","","","","","","","",""]  Used code to determine length of each row and they were all 9

Comment: *setValues will assume the greated size to be the correct one and hence the discrepancy* That's not true. There's no assumption whatsoever. It just iterates provided array from first to last. The range however remains constant=the arguments provided to `getRange()`.  Note that the OP excluded/changed/mixed up the error messages  causing  this incorrect assumption.

Comment: @TheMaster we say the same thing. It will iterate over every row. If a row has a different size than the next one (hence rows with different sizes) the script will fail. The OP changed his question. I provided a solution that works for his original question. Now he added a new code that generates a **new error**. Feel free to help him out if you want. I don't think I should do.

Comment: You're probably right. Reading your answer again, I might've interpreted it wrong- Thanks to OP's confusing edits

Answer (score 1):

According to Google's Docs - [range.setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) - The size of the two-dimensional array must match the size of the range.

`mysteryArr[i]` must have the same length for all `i`.

Comment: Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug num rows: 3
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug num cols in row 0 is 9
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug ["question1","","","","","","","",""]
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug num cols in row 1 is 9
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug ["question1","","","","","","","",""]
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug num cols in row 2 is 9
Dec 22, 2020, 3:38:40 PM Debug ["question1","","","","","","","",""]  Used code to determine length of each row and they were all 9

Comment: @L.Klein in the for loop that you are using to debug `maCols = mysteryArr[0].length` means that you are always logging the result of the first element of `mysteryArr`

Answer (score 1):

Equalize Length of All Rows of the array:

```
function equalize(arr) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  let m=0;
  arr.forEach(r=>{if(r.length>m)m=r.length;});
  let orr=arr.map(r=>{while(r.length<m){r.push('');}return r;});
  sh.getRange(1,1,orr.length,m).setValues(orr);
}
```